# how to create a form to create a new account then in a second form you can login to the account that has been created

Tags: c#

i want to create a form to create a new account then in a second form you can login to the account that has been created.

[this is the first screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Isu5M.png)
[this is the secound](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqVMz.png)

here is the create btn code:

```
public partial class NewAccountForm : Form
{
    Accounts account1;

    public NewAccountForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 login = new Form1();
        this.Hide();
        login.Show();
    }

    private void btncreat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // here am lost
        int interest = '0';
        char type = '0';
        double amount = '0' ;
        double balance = '0';

        switch (cboType.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: type = '1'; break;
            case 1: type = '2'; break;
        }

        account1.setname(txtName.Text);
        account1.setCode(txtpinCode.Text);
        account1.setcontact(txtContact.Text);

        Saveing cust1 = new Saveing(interest, txtName.Text, txtContact.Text,
            txtpinCode.Text, type, amount,balance);

        Data.CSaveing.Add(cust1); //SList shows because its static if remove static will not appears

        txtName.Text = "";
        txtContact.Text = "";
        txtpinCode.Text = ""; 
    }
}
```

this is the login form code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtCode.Text.Equals(txtCode.Text))
        {
            int i;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Step = 1;
            timer1.Start();

            for (i = 0; i <= 50; i++)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = i;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter correct Pin Code");
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewAccountForm naf = new NewAccountForm();
        this.Hide();
        naf.Show();
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.PerformStep();
        if (progressBar1.Value == 99)
        {
            LoginForm login = new LoginForm();
            this.Hide();
            login.Show();
        }
    }

    private void label3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void label4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

}

Comment: please add your second form's code

Comment: What does Accounts do? if(txtCode.Text.Equals(txtCode.Text)) == if(true) ?  Basically you want to store all your Accounts in a List<Account>. In your NewAccountForm add an Account to that List. In your LoginForm just iterate over the List until you find the desired Account.

Comment: Do you have a question... [How to ask a Question at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i want login button to check in the collection for the account that has been created if its exists then it will login to the account from his pin code but i don't know how to do it T_T.

Comment: the problem is that they are on different forms so how am i going to make the login button to check if this user exsist or not

Comment: check the pictures above i did the same sequence on the form but i dont know how to do some of the codes

Comment: nope its just a welcome screen press on the button to create a new account then on the creating account form you can login with out creating an account

Comment: this what was required from me to do by my teacher O_O

Comment: FYI... you should edit your question and not use the answer portion to update your question. A moderator will let you know that this is not proper.

Answer (score 0):

Null Refrence Exception was unhandled

[when i try do create a new account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzjLb.png)

```
public partial class NewAccountForm : Form
{
    public NewAccountForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    Accounts account1;


    private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {




    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 login = new Form1();
        this.Hide();
        login.Show();
    }

    private void btnlogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int interest = '0';
        char type = '0';
        double amount = '0' ;
        double balance = '0';





        switch (cboType.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case 0: type = '1'; break;

            case 1: type = '2'; break;

        }



        Saveing cust1 = new Saveing(interest, txtName.Text, txtContact.Text,
            txtpinCode.Text, type, amount,balance);

        Data.CSaveing.Add(cust1); //SList shows because its static if remove static will not appears


        account1.setname(txtName.Text);
        account1.setCode(txtpinCode.Text);
        account1.setcontact(txtContact.Text);




    }
    }
}
```